# Projections when using google maps and rest service on openlayers

Tags: openlayers-2, coordinate-system, google-maps, rest

I am trying to use a rest service on an openlayers map that has 2 google maps layers.  The google map layer is set to it's own custom projection (which I had to code into the library by hand, but I believe is the standard EPSG of 900913)..  However the layer that I would like to sit on the google map is in Oklahoma State Plane North.

```
var arcrest = new OpenLayers.Layer.ArcGIS93Rest("Rest Layer", arcserver_rest, {
                            LAYERS: 'show:18,19,20,21,29,30,31',
                            IMAGESR: '2267',
                            BBOXSR: '2267',
                            FORMAT: 'png',
                            TRANSPARENT: true
                        },
                        {
                        isBaseLayer: false,
                        units: 'ft',
                        maxExtent: new OpenLayers.Bounds(2034036.00510709,  136689.343284666, 2069119.14841628, 148575.857284666)
                        }
                        );
```

Why is this projecting into the Congo, and not Oklahoma?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to specify the srs [parameter](http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.13/doc/apidocs/files/OpenLayers/Layer/ArcGIS93Rest-js.html) of your layer:

srs : '32024' //NAD27 or
srs : '32126' //NAD83

Comment: As it turns out, I had to change the map documents projection to world mercator verses a local state plane coordinate system.   Thanks for the reply..